# Picklist field value being mapped does not display on original object but does display on mapped object - change code to show on both - how?

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am still learning and have created this code that triggers when:

On Enrollment (custom object)

When the user changes the enrollment status (picklist field) to 'graduated', it populates the graduation date (date field) with today's date.
The code then carries the graduation date (date field) and program type (4 different checkboxes) onto the Contact details page.

It works just fine, the only issue I am having is that once the code is triggered, it removes the value of the Program Type field on Enrollment - it just disappears? I need this field to be visible.

On Enrollment:

- Enrollment Status
- Program Type: (Picklist) 
  Online Ed
  On-Campus
  Corporate Training
  Learnership
- Graduation Date (Date)

On Contact:

- Graduation Date (date)
- Online Ed (checkbox)
- On-Campus (checkbox)
- Corporate Training (checkbox)
- Learnership (checkbox)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Apex class:

public class UpdateProgramType {
    public static void WhenProgramTypeUpdated(List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> enrollmentListUpdate){
        try{
            List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> enrollmentList = new List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c>();
            List<contact> contactList = new List<contact>();
            List<contact> contactListUpdated = new List<contact>();
            set<id> IdList = new set<Id>();
            enrollmentList = [select id, hed__Contact__c, hed__Enrollment_Status__c,Program_Type__c
                             from hed__Program_Enrollment__c
                             where id in:enrollmentListUpdate
                             and hed__Enrollment_Status__c = 'Graduated'];

            for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c en: enrollmentList) { 
                IdList.add(en.hed__Contact__c);
            }

            contactList = [select id, Online_Ed__c, On_Campus__c, Corporate_Training__c,Learnership__c from contact where id in : IdList];

            for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c enn: enrollmentList) {
                for(contact en:contactList){
                    if(enn.hed__Contact__c == en.id && enn.hed__Enrollment_Status__c == 'Graduated' && enn.Program_Type__c == 'Online Ed' ){
                        en.Online_Ed__c = true;
                        contactListUpdated.add(en);
                }
                    if(enn.hed__Contact__c == en.id && enn.hed__Enrollment_Status__c == 'Graduated' && enn.Program_Type__c == 'On-Campus' ){
                        en.On_Campus__c = true;
                        contactListUpdated.add(en);
                }
                    if(enn.hed__Contact__c == en.id && enn.hed__Enrollment_Status__c == 'Graduated' && enn.Program_Type__c == 'Corporate Training' ){
                        en.Corporate_Training__c = true;
                        contactListUpdated.add(en);
                }
                    if(enn.hed__Contact__c == en.id && enn.hed__Enrollment_Status__c == 'Graduated' && enn.Program_Type__c == 'Learnership' ){
                        en.Learnership__c = true;
                        contactListUpdated.add(en);
                    }
                }
            }
            update contactListUpdated;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            system.debug('Error is -> '+ e.getMessage() + 'at Line -> '+ e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

Apex trigger:

```
trigger updateprogramtype on hed__Program_Enrollment__c (After insert, After update) {

    if((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) && trigger.isAfter)
    {
        Updateprogramtype.WhenProgramTypeUpdated(trigger.new);
    }

}
```

Test code:

```
@isTest
public class UpdateProgramType_Test {
    static testMethod void testInsertandUpdate(){
        //Given
        Contact contact = new Contact(LastName = 'Brown');
        contact.Online_Ed__c = true;
        contact.LastName = 'LastName';
        insert contact;

        hed__Program_Enrollment__c enrollment = new hed__Program_Enrollment__c (
                hed__Contact__c = contact.Id,
                Program_Type__c = 'Online Ed'
        );

        insert enrollment;

        Test.startTest();
        // When
        enrollment.hed__Enrollment_Status__c = 'Graduated';
        update enrollment;

        //Then
        contact = [SELECT Online_Ed__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =:contact.Id];
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(true, contact.Online_Ed__c);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[![
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3qrz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3qrz.png)

[image]

Comment: help me to understand, field not visible means field is not visible on the record page or the update which you made is not reflecting after save?

Comment: The use case you mentioned above can be achieved without code. Use the Process Builder to update the contact record.

Comment: @LokeshKumar The update is reflecting on the Contact object, but the Program type field value is removed. I wish I could show a screenshot - it would explain it better.

Comment: @LokeshKumar This code works perfectly, it just strangely takes away the Program Type value that is inputted on the Enrollment object.

Comment: Do you have any trigger written on the contact object? Also the trigger on the hed__Program_Enrollment__c has only one method?

Comment: Did you check if there is a trigger/WF/PB on contact which is updating "Program type". Did you try raising Debug Logs and check the transaction?

Comment: @ChloeBrown Can you enable a debug log to verify if any other code is updating this field Program Type. Or go to the field and click on "Where is this used"

Comment: @LokeshKumar I am not great with coding language -  "hed__Program_Enrollment__c has only one method?" - is this referring to the trigger?

Comment: @VeeraG will check this now and update you!

Comment: @LokeshKumar Oh, I see it is being affected by a Flow! Hmmm. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @ChloeBrown Cool! Please let me know if you need any help to learn apex coding. I can help you here is my LinkedIn profile https://www.linkedin.com/in/lokesh-kumar-b9257996/

Comment: @LokeshKumar Do you have any comments regarding this code? Is there anything that could be written better?